# Google sitemap namespace confusion

Tags: xml, namespaces, sitemap

Here the structure of my sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>somefile.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

**somefile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
  <loc>[some url]</loc>
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="[some url]" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="[some url]?lang=en" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="[some url]?lang=fr" />
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

Here is Google's error message:

> Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the
>   namespace. Expected: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
>   Found: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml Tag: urlset

I guess I'm missing something, information on the Internet are confusing. What's is the right syntax? Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by replace add the xhtml namespace to all the 'link' tags.

Replacing

```
<link
```

with

```
<xhtml:link
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to your URL:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="[some url]" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
```